# How to show thousands separator for pandas value counts?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was using value counts method of pandas dataframe and found that it outputs the integer without thousands separator. How can we get the output with thousands separator?

## MWE:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,2,2]*10000})

df['A'].value_counts()

1    30000
2    20000
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

## Attempts

```py
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int_kind': '{:,}'.format})
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,}'.format

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,2,2]*10000})

df['A'].value_counts()

# still could not get thousands separator
1    30000
2    20000
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you set `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,}'.format`
it will work for floats not ints

```
df['A'].value_counts().astype(float)
1   30,000.0
2   20,000.0
```

Comment: Can this be set with styler property? I see the precision option, but not the thousands one.

Comment: You would have to test it out, I'm not sure